# Compositor does not insert Render Layers node after checking Use Nodes

Tags: rendering, node-editor, image, output

Blender 3.6.4
Windows 10 latest updates

In Blender 3.6.4, after rendering in the image editor completes, I enter the Compositor and check Use Nodes, no Render Layers / Output node is inserted.

If I do the same operation in Blender 2.93 LTS or 4.1, checking Use Nodes creates a Render Layer / Output node.

Comment: Weird I've just tested with 3.6.4 and it works fine

Comment: Are they there, but  disappeared off the edge of the region? (In the region, A to select all nodes, followed by Numpad '.' to centre the view on selected)

Comment: I have read through your comments and I tested to see if the nodes were hidden. They were not hidden.  Thank you for your feedback and assistance. I'll keeping digging.

Comment: I think it was an AddOn. I removed Blender 3.6.5 from my computer and cleaned out any related files. Re-installed it with Blender Launcher and it works as I expected: clicking Use Nodes in Compositing brings up the Render Layers and output nodes. So I will proceed from this point and see if I can figure out what or which addon caused it. Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this question might sound stupid: Are you sure they are not there? If you check *Use Nodes* and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to render, does it render or is it just throwing an error? If it renders, the nodes are there.

Without the nodes you'll get this error, even if there were many nodes and only the *Composite* output node was missing it would not render until you uncheck *Use Nodes*.

[image: error missing compositor output]

So if it renders, it is more likely that they are somewhere outside of the *Compositor* window's view. To make sure they are not just somewhere out of sight hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all that might be there, then <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to *Frame Selected*. This should zoom the window so that all selected nodes are in the center of the window.

The reason this could be happening is, as stupid as it sounds, you have for example a large nodetree in the *Shader Editor* or *Geometry Node Editor* and moved the view around: their layout is somehow (for whatever reason) linked. Moving one editor window around to view different parts will change what you see in the other editors as well.

And if you save it like this as the *Startup File*, it will always be out of sight when enabling the *Compositor* even in a new scene. Or when the nodes are really gone and not just out of sight, the same thing could have happened: they were deleted somehow and you saved this configuration as *Startup File*.

Comment: I think it was an AddOn. I removed Blender 3.6.5 from my computer and cleaned out any related files. Re-installed it with Blender Launcher and it works as I expected: clicking Use Nodes in Compositing brings up the Render Layers and output nodes. So I will proceed from this point and see if I can figure out what or which addon caused it. Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: @Mark You're welcome...I guess I would have simply set it up by adding the nodes in the _Compositor_ and saving as startup file instead of removing everything and cleaning all files, then re-installing it (and probably lose all my custom settings), but to each his own 

Comment: I did try to save the nodes in the startup file but it didn't work either. In the past I have had an addon interfere with another Blender process. Thank you again for your assistance.